# firebase storage in image not generate access token in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-storage

```
$image = $request->file('image'); //image file from frontend  
$name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
$firebase_storage_path = 'notificationImage/';  
$localfolder = public_path('firebase-temp-uploads') .'/';  
$extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();  
$file      = $name;  
if ($image->move($localfolder, $file)) {  
    $uploadedfile = fopen($localfolder.$file, 'r');  
    $storage->getBucket()->upload($uploadedfile, ['name' => $firebase_storage_path . $file]);  
    //will remove from local laravel folder  
    //unlink($localfolder . $file);  
    echo 'success';  
} else {  
    echo 'error';  
}
```

[image]
[image]
Images upload on firebase storage folder but token not generate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your script does not set an access token. As you've figured out, the web interface does this by default. In such cases it's useful to check the files metadata.

You can use `gsutil`, which is also quite handy for other tasks. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install

But of course you can also use the Google Cloud Console, which gives you more details then Firebase does. https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser

So here's a file I've uploaded from the web:

```
$ gsutil ls -L  gs://foo.appspot.com/profiles/bar/avatar.jpg
gs://foo.appspot.com/profiles/bar/avatar.jpg:
    Creation time:          Sat, 20 Mar 2021 13:56:00 GMT
    Update time:            Sun, 21 Mar 2021 12:18:22 GMT
    Storage class:          STANDARD
    Content-Length:         68107
    Content-Type:           image/jpeg
    Metadata:
        firebaseStorageDownloadTokens:abcd1234-e749-4473-91c9-07cf2f27ede2
    Hash (crc32c):          hHZfWQ==

    Hash (md5):             W2sIeTGeiktc6i+eDLkeqA==
    ETag:                   CNL+y4qDv+8CEAM=
    Generation:             1616248560615250
    Metageneration:         3
    ACL:                    [
  {
    …
```

The metadata field `firebaseStorageDownloadTokens` actually contains the same access token you seen in the Firebase web ui.

Unfortunately I don't know PHP, but it should be fairly simple to generate a UUID for the `firebaseStorageDownloadTokens` field and add it as metadata when uploading the file.